# Always discoverable Classic Bluetooth module

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I recently purchased a Bluetooth device which connects to both my iOS and Android devices.

The device uses Classic Bluetooth and seems to be quite stable on my Android device *however* recently, I have noticed a few issues with the connection on my iOS devices. It seems to occasionally become a bit unstable.

While trying to figure out if the problem was on my end, I noticed that the **Bluetooth device is actually always discoverable**. I did a little digging and have been unable to find much information regarding this practice.

I've read up on how Bluetooth selects a channel over the 2.4G band, and how there are 3 out of the 80 channels which are used for discovery. Does this mean that the device is always on 1 of those 3 channels because it is always discoverable? Does it also mean that it's unable to change channel in the event of being on a noisy frequency?

Again, I'm assuming this is bad practice in terms of setting up a Classic Bluetooth connection but I haven't done too much work myself with Bluetooth and haven't had much luck finding more information regarding the issue. Could it also present issues of other devices attempting a connection while a connection is already made? I believe BLE devices become hidden once they've made a connection however I don't think this is the case for Classic Bluetooth.